# Debian 10 Buster Unknown error executing apt-key

Tags: debian

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

```
apt-get update
Hit:1 https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49.3 kB]
Err:1 https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease [46.7 kB]
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Unknown error executing apt-key
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Unknown error executing apt-key
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Unknown error executing apt-key
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-backports/InRelease  Unknown error executing apt-key
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/buster/InRelease  Unknown error executing apt-key
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Содержимое sources.list:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib
```

Вывод apt-key:

```
apt-key update
Warning: 'apt-key update' is deprecated and should not be used anymore!
Note: In your distribution this command is a no-op and can therefore be removed safely.
```

Выполнение:

```
apt-get install gnupg libgcrypt20 -o AllowUnauthenticated=true
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
gnupg is already the newest version (2.2.12-1+deb10u1).
libgcrypt20 is already the newest version (1.8.4-5).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libclamav9 libcurl3-nss libmspack0 libtfm1
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Содержимое /etc/apt/sources.list добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: nightflash, добавил.

Comment: "sudo apt-key update"
Что выдаст эта команда?

Comment: nightflash, прикрепил.

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить команду: sudo apt-get install gnupg libgcrypt20 -o AllowUnauthenticated=true

Comment: Не помогло.((((

Comment: dirmngr поставьте

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему. В моём случае сам накосячил и решим в итоге тоже сам. Проблема была в том, что в папке /usr/bin были права 754, а должно быть 755 на те команды, на которые у меня было 754 в целях безопасности.